# How to customize the Document List in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

In the repository there be will different document lists.i.e there will be Data dictionary, user homes,Guest homes etc. when I change the view to "detailed view", it displays Favorite, like, comments links. where will I have to modify if I dont want to show them. Can you tell in which file i have to comment the code for not displaying those links. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Is this in the Alfresco Share interface or the older Alfresco Explorer one?

Comment: @Gagravarr Its in Alfresco Share.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted a "modular" answer to this question, this answer is to show how I handled this issue.

**Context:** Alfresco 4.2.f, project Maven from the `org.alfresco.maven.archetype:alfresco-amp-archetype:1.1.1` archetype, I put everything in the embedded JAR when possible.

Create a module extension for share (see [this blog](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/09/04/customizing-the-share-header-menu-part-1/) for more details). Here is my extension file:

*src/main/resources/alfresco/site-data/extensions/my-custom-extension.xml*

```xml
<extension>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>Main module of my custom extension</id>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
      <customizations>
        <customization>
          <!-- Order matters here! target before source, always! -->
          <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco</targetPackageRoot>
          <sourcePackageRoot>my-custom.main</sourcePackageRoot>
        </customization>
      </customizations>
    </module>
  </modules>
</extension>
```

In the `documentlibrary` component of your module package, create this FTL in order to declare a javascript:

*src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/my-custom/main/components/documentlibrary/documentlist-v2.get.html.ftl*

```
<#-- Add a Javascript declaration -->
<@markup id="my-custom-js"  target="js" action="after">
  <@script type="text/javascript" group="documentlibrary"
      src="${url.context}/res/my-custom/main/components/documentlibrary/documentlist.js"/>
</@>
```

In the resources (META-INF), under `documentlibrary` component, create the Javascript:

*src/main/resources/META-INF/my-custom/main/components/documentlibrary/documentlist.js*

```js
YAHOO.lang.augmentObject(Alfresco.DocumentList.prototype, {

  // Possible values: i18nLabel, lockBanner, syncFailed, syncTransientError
  // date, size, name, version, description, tags, categories
  myCustomDisabledRenderers: ["description", "version", "tags"],

  // Possible values: favourites, likes, comments, quickShare
  myCustomDisabledSocials: ["favourites", "comments", "likes", "quickShare"],

  myCustomIsSocialDisabled: function(propertyName) {
    return Alfresco.util.arrayContains(
        this.myCustomDisabledSocials, propertyName);
  },

  myCustomIsRendererDisabled: function(propertyName) {
    if (Alfresco.util.arrayContains(
        this.myCustomDisabledRenderers, propertyName)) {
      return true;
    }
    // Disable the social renderer when all the social features are
    // disabled
    if (propertyName === "social" && this.myCustomDisabledSocials.length == 4) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },

  /** Helper function to disable socials
   * propertyName must be one of "favourites", "comments", "likes", "quickShare"
   */
  myCustomDisableSocial: function(propertyName) {
    if (!Alfresco.util.arrayContains(
        this.myCustomDisabledSocials, propertyName)) {
      this.myCustomDisabledSocials.push(propertyName);
    }
  },

  // Custom registerRenderer for social features, originally defined in:
  // webapps/share/components/documentlibrary/documentlist.js:2134
  myCustomSocialRegisterRenderer: function(record) {
    var jsNode = record.jsNode;
    var html = "";
    // Current usage of the separator variable allow to change the order
    // of the different social features (the 'if' blocks below) without 
    // changing their content
    var separator = "";
    /* Favourite / Likes / Comments */
    if (!this.myCustomIsSocialDisabled("favourites")) {
      html += '<span class="item item-social' + separator + '">' + 
          Alfresco.DocumentList.generateFavourite(this, record) + 
          '</span>';
      separator = " item-separator";
    }
    if (!this.myCustomIsSocialDisabled("likes")) {
      html += '<span class="item item-social' + separator + '">' + 
          Alfresco.DocumentList.generateLikes(this, record) + 
          '</span>';
      separator = " item-separator";
    }
    if (!this.myCustomIsSocialDisabled("comments") && 
        jsNode.permissions.user.CreateChildren) {
      html += '<span class="item item-social' + separator + '">' + 
          Alfresco.DocumentList.generateComments(this, record) + 
          '</span>';
      separator = " item-separator";
    }
    if (!this.myCustomIsSocialDisabled("quickShare") && !record.node.isContainer && 
        Alfresco.constants.QUICKSHARE_URL) {
      html += '<span class="item' + separator + '">' + 
          Alfresco.DocumentList.generateQuickShare(this, record) + 
          '</span>';
      separator = " item-separator";
    }

    return html;
  },

  // Overwrite registerRenderer which was originally defined in:
  // webapps/share/components/documentlibrary/documentlist.js:1789
  registerRenderer: function DL_registerRenderer(propertyName, renderer) {
    if (Alfresco.util.isValueSet(propertyName) && 
        Alfresco.util.isValueSet(renderer) && 
        !this.myCustomIsRendererDisabled(propertyName)) {
      if (propertyName === "social") {
        this.renderers[propertyName] = this.myCustomSocialRegisterRenderer;
      } else {
        this.renderers[propertyName] = renderer;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


}, true);
```

Then you can disable the links by updating `myCustomDisabledRenderers` and/or `mySocialDisabledRenderers`.

This way also allows you to create a module that disable (for example) the "comments on documents" or "likes on document" feature independently in only 6 easy steps!

**Example, how to make a module that only disable comments on documents in 6 steps**

1. Important: first remove the "comment disabling" from the `documentlist.js` of the main module.

   ```js
   myCustomDisabledSocials: ["favourites", "likes", "quickShare"],
   ```
2. Create a new module "my-custom.nocomment" with the same structure.

   ```xml
   <extension>
     <modules>
       <module>
         <id>Main module of my custom extension</id>
         [...]
       </module>
       <module>
         <id>No comment module of my custom extension</id>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
         <customizations>
           <customization>
             <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco</targetPackageRoot>
             <sourcePackageRoot>my-custom.nocomment</sourcePackageRoot>
           </customization>
         </customizations>
       </module>
     </modules>
   </extension>
   ```
3. Add the FTL...

   *src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/my-custom/nocomment/components/documentlibrary/documentlist-v2.get.html.ftl*

   ```
   <#-- Add a Javascript declaration -->
   <@markup id="my-custom-js"  target="js" action="after">
     <@script type="text/javascript" group="documentlibrary"
         src="${url.context}/res/my-custom/nocomment/components/documentlibrary/documentlist.js"/>
   </@>
   ```
4. then the Javascript...

   *src/main/resources/META-INF/my-custom/nocomment/components/documentlibrary/documentlist.js*

   ```js
   Alfresco.DocumentList.prototype.myCustomDisableSocial("comment");
   ```
5. and then I'm happy, clap along if you feel like everything's just got smooth!
6. Notes:

   - The `nocomment` module depends on the `main` module.
   - It is important for the `nocomment` module to be loaded **after** the `main` module (in `http://localhost:8080/share/page/modules/deploy`).
   - In order for the `nocomment` module to be complete, you also need to disable comments from the document details page, see below.

**Disable comments from the document details page**

Even if, this one is documented elsewhere, I spent so much time searching around these few days that I feel like I need to be as comprehensive as possible.

*src/main/resources/alfresco/site-data/extensions/my-custom-extension.xml*

Add this to your `my-custom.nocomment` module declaration and you will get rid of the comments form and list from the document details page.

```xml
[...]
<module>
  <id>No comment module of my custom extension</id>
  [...]
  <components>
    <component>
      <region-id>comments</region-id>
      <source-id>document-details</source-id>
      <scope>template</scope>
      <sub-components>
        <sub-component id="default">
          <evaluations>
            <evaluation id="guaranteedToHide">
              <render>false</render>
            </evaluation>
          </evaluations>
        </sub-component>
      </sub-components>
    </component>
  </components>
</module>
[...]
```

src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/my-custom/nocomment/components/node-details/node-header.get.js

This is for disabling the button on the header of the document details page.

```js
// Disable comments
for (var i = 0; i < model.widgets.length; i++) {
  if (model.widgets[i].id == "NodeHeader") {
    model.widgets[i].options.showComments = false;
  }
}
// And since it does not work, disable comments this way too
model.showComments = "false";
```

**Note:** I did not test these snippets, they have been taken from my project after "anonymization" (basically renaming the module). Let me know if you find mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is more than likely generated by client-side JavaScript. You should use share-config-custom.xml to set Share to development mode, like this:

```
<alfresco-config>
    <!-- Put Share Client in debug mode -->
    <config replace="true">
        <flags>
            <client-debug>true</client-debug>
            <client-debug-autologging>false</client-debug-autologging>
        </flags>
    </config>
</alfresco-config>
```

Then, use firebug or your browser's developer console to step through the client-side JavaScript. You should be able to find the point where the document library elements are rendered.

You can override Alfresco's client-side JavaScript components with your own components. Please put them in your own namespace to avoid collisions with Alfresco's.

Comment: thank you bro for the answer. I want  more clarification  1.Where do i need to place this share-config-custom.xml in the share? Is it in following  share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco location? 2.Can you tell which is the client side javascript to override?

Comment: I have placed share-config-custom.xml in share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco  location. After adding that file , everything is blank. I am not able to view the login page too. If i Want to override javascript where i have to do it? Thank you in Advance.

Comment: It goes in WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-extension. If you want to override JavaScript, you'll use YUI to extend the existing components and your client-side JavaScript file will reside in the web root of the Share WAR. If you've never customized Share before, I highly recommend you start with something simple, like a Dashlet or a UI action, see http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/05/08/1592, http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-actions/actions-article-2ed.pdf, and http://code.google.com/p/share-extras.

Comment: Thank you bro.I will go through the above links.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by commenting the {social} line in file share-documentlibrary-config.xml in share/src/alfresco/share-document-config

```
...
<metadata-templates>
   <!-- Default (fallback) -->
     <template id="default">
        <line index="10" id="date">{date}{size}</line>
        <line index="20" id="description" view="detailed">{description}</line>
        <line index="30" id="tags" view="detailed">{tags}</line>
        <line index="40" id="categories" view="detailed" evaluator="evaluator.doclib.metadata.hasCategories">{categories}</line> -->
   <!-- <line index="50" id="social" view="detailed">{social}</line> -->
     </template>
...
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand well your question - you're trying to hide some columns from particular view in alfresco explorer? If so, you need to edit /jsp/browse/browse.jsp file, but I think that's not a good idea. Maybe implementing your own NodePropertyResolver should be better way, have look at my older blogpost on this topic: http://www.shmoula.cz/adding-columns-to-custom-browse-jsp/

Comment: I am not trying to hide columns. And i am working on Alfresco  Share. I am trying to remove some links like comments, Favorite, like etc in the document list view. I want to know in which .ftl file i need to remove those links. I searched for it, but was not able to find that .ftl file.

Comment: Ah, I see, so not Alfresco explorer. I'm not familiar with Share, but I thing the way is to use [SurfBug](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/Surf_v4_components_Share.html) tool to find that particular component you want to make changes in.

Comment: Yeah Im using SurfBug itself. but for that particular link i cannot find any code. Anyways thanks for your reply.

Comment: The best strategy is to search over webapps/share for ids found by SurfBug :-). I think file you are interested in is in /share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary directory - start with documentlist.* files and keep going...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of it is in: \opt\alfresco-4.0.d\tomcat\webapps\share\components\documentlibrary\documentlist.js
I think the trick is in this.registerRenderer("social"...) to return html before line 1981 (after favorites before likes) supposing you want to keep at least faorite